# Is the boundary $\partial A$ of $A \subset X$ contained into $\overline{A}$?

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space and let $A \subset X$.
Let $\overline{A}$ be the closure of A and let $\partial A = \{p \in X \mid \forall U \ni p, U \text{ open}:U \cap A \ne \emptyset \text{ and } U \cap A^c \ne \emptyset\}$ be the boundary of A.
I wanna prove that $\partial A \subset \overline{A}$.
I've sketched the following proof, but I don't know if it's right.

**Proof**: If $a \in \partial A$, then $\forall U \ni a, U \text{ open}$ we have also that $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$. The are two cases:

1. $a \in A$ (in this case we're not sure that $(U \backslash \{a\}) \cap A \ne \emptyset$).
2. $a \notin A$. So there exists $a' \ne a$ such that $a' \in (U \backslash \{a\}) \cap A$, then $a \in A'$, where $A'$ is the derived set of $A$

In either case, $a \in A \cup A' = \overline{A}$. Finally $\partial A \subset \overline{A}$

Comment: You don't need $(U\setminus \{a\}) \cap A \neq \varnothing$. One always has $A \subset \overline{A}$, so $a \in A \implies a \in \overline{A}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dichotomy comes from your definition of $\overline{A}$ as $A \cup A'$. One argument based on this definition: suppose $x \in \partial A$' if $x \in A$ we're done (as $x \in \overline{A}$) we assume it's not. Any open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ and this is necessarily in a point $\neq x$, as $x \notin A$, hence $x \in A'$ and we're again done.

Using the alternative correct definition:

$$\overline{A}=\{x \in X: \forall U \ni x \text{ open }: U \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$$

the inclusion $\partial A \subseteq \overline{A}$ is immediate: we just drop one condition in the definition of $\partial A$ that you gave.

Comment: Ok, thank you: I didn't know that definition of $\overline{A}$. But given the definition of $\partial A$, and given that the only facts that I know are the ones that I've written, my proof is correct? I keep asking it because I'm from computer science and I'm approaching to mathematics in my free time: I'm a sort of newbie in this field...

Comment: @FedericoBelotti The first paragraph is a correct argument based on your definition. It's basically the same as your point 2. So based on the trivial case $x \in A$ and the more interesting case $x \notin A$.

Answer (score 2):

No need to consider two cases. By definition of $\partial A$, every open set to which $a$ belongs contains elemeents of $A$ and therefore $\in\overline A$.

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Maybe my proof is too pedantic

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

If $T\subseteq X$ is any subset and $p\in X$ is any point then the property "for any open neighbourhood $U\subseteq X$ of $p$ we have $U\cap T\neq\emptyset$" is equivalent to "$p\in\overline{T}$".

That alone is enough to prove your assertion. But there's more, you can easily rewrite the definition of $\partial A$ as $\partial A=\overline{A^c}\cap\overline{A}$.

Comment: The two properties are equivalent because $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$?

Comment: @FedericoBelotti Ops, I meant $\overline{A^c}\cap\overline{A}$.

Comment: Ok. I've to think about that :)